# Regex to find String with square bracket and replace

Tags: java, regex, replace

my current Code is

```
`
String text= "[School_Teacher_Name] is our new member, So please congratulate [School_Teacher_Name] .";
String tag = "[School_Teacher_Name]";
String value= "Yash Mathur";
String str1 = tag.substring(1, tag.length()-1);
String reg = "/\\["+str1+"\\]/";

if(text.contains(tag)){
   return text.replaceAll(reg, value).trim();
}
else{
   return text;
}`
```

I dont have much experience in regex. my code is not replacing any value, Please help me out.

Comment: replace with what? the same string?

Comment: This is NOT JavaScript. This is Java. The two are *completely different* programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If I don't misunderstood you requirements** then you can do this way. [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/TlD3LR/1)

**Java**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "\\[(School_Teacher_Name)]";
final String string = "[School_Teacher_Name] is our new member, So please congratulate [School_Teacher_Name] .";
final String subst = "Yash Mathur";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

**Javascript**

```js
const regex = /\[(School_Teacher_Name)]/gm;
const str = `[School_Teacher_Name] is our new member, So please congratulate [School_Teacher_Name] .`;
const subst = `Yash Mathur`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: Thanks allot, It worked, I do not require pattern and matcher, my String class method replaceAll takes regex.

Comment: @SurendraKumarJaiswal You're welcome, Glad it helps you somehow

Comment: May I ask why at end "]", we didnot use "//]" ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove forward slashes from your regex.

Change

```
String reg = "/\\["+str1+"\\]/";
```

to

```
String reg = "\\["+str1+"\\]";
```

**Output**

```
Yash Mathur is our new member, So please congratulate Yash Mathur .
```

PS - In this case it's better to use `text.replace(tag, value)` instead of `text.replaceAll(reg, value)`

Answer (score 0):

It's far easier with [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
let teacher = 'Yash Mathur';
let test = `${teacher} is our new member, so please congratulate ${teacher}.`;

console.log(test);
```

Comment: Well, then I guess use [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) :)